# How to construct a G-extension of a category C?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, mathematical-physics, fusion-categories

Note: I'm a physicist so this will be phrased somewhat in physics language.

Suppose we have a unitary modular tensor category $\mathcal{C}$. In physics language, we can think of $\mathcal{C}$ as representing a topological phase and the objects of the category as representing the quasiparticles of this phase.

In some cases, the fusion and braiding rules of $\mathcal{C}$ are invariant under the permutation of the quasiparticles (objects of $\mathcal{C}$) by the action of a finite group $G$. If the symmetry action is not anomalous then it is known that there exists a $G$-extension of $\mathcal{C}$ (see Fusion Categories and Homotopy Theory, 2009, Etingof et al)

**My question:** Given $\mathcal{C}$ and the action of $G$ on the objects of $\mathcal{C}$, does there exist a simple way of constructing the $G$-extension? In the physicist language, I would like a $G$-grading of the set of quasiparticles in the $G$-extension of $\mathcal{C}$.

Thanks!

Comment: I know that probably doesn't help a lot, but I would first look at invertible bimodules of $\mathcal{C}$, \ie determine the Brauer-Picard group $BrPic(\mathcal{C})$ or some subgroup. A group hom $D:G\rightarrow BrPic(\mathcal{C})$ will give you a $G$-extension (minus the obstructions etc). The $G$-extension will be $D = \bigoplus_{g} D(g)$. I'm sure ENO 2009 has all the more details you want.

Answer (score 0):

A good answer to the subject is Etingof et. al's paper "[Weakly group-theoretical and solvable fusion categories](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0809.3031.pdf)".

The TL;DR is that when you have a $G$-action you can take the $G$-invariants ("equivariantization"). This is then reversible with "de-equivariantization", which gets you back your starting category. Hopefully this answers your question.